# Validity of `[subject] let [verb] [object]`

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis, indicative

I'm writing my statement of purpose for grad school, but used a sentence that I'm not sure is grammatical.

> I inevitably decided on electrical engineering, but never **let die** my love of language.

I'm a bit confused as to the validity of mechanics of `[subject] let [verb] [object]`

Is this OK?

Comment: I think what you wrote is okay, however to me it doesn't read well. How about this: "I inevitably decided on electrical engineering, but I never let my love of language die." Or an alternative: "........ but never let go of my love of language."

Comment: It is perfectly grammatical. But I don't understand why you say the subject follows the verb. The first word of the sentence 'I', is the subject of both 'decided' and 'let die'.

Comment: It's "grammatical", but the **[subject] let [verb] [object]** form with no preposition would normally only occur in archaic text, poetic contexts, or colloquial speech where the preposition might sometimes be deleted in, *Let **go** [**of**] my arm!* or similar. So although we're familiar with Shakespeare's *Let slip the dogs of war*, I certainly can't imagine a driving instructor saying, for example, *Let slip the clutch and move the car slowly forward*.

Comment: @WS2 Oops... hadn't had my coffee yet. I edited it!

Comment: To that very different question I could not possibly enlarge on the excellent answer given by @Araucaria, below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is grammatical, if somewhat flowery. The reason it is acceptable is that the noun phrase *my love of language* is relatively long. If you tried it with a short noun phrase, for example a pronoun, it would be considered ungrammatical:

- *I never let die it.
- I never let die the passion I had for ballroom dancing.

This phenomenon is called *heavy noun phrase shift*. It allows us to move long noun phrases from their normal position in the verb phrase and put them at the end of the clause.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments so far.

> I inevitably decided on electrical engineering, but never let die my love of language.

1. The above is perfectly correct English grammar. It is slightly formal or poetic.
2. nickson104's suggestion, "but I never let my love of language die" is how most people would speak it.
3. Here is the grammatical structure of your original:

I inevitably decided on electrical engineering, but [I] never let [to] die my love of language.

The subject is 'I' and 'die' is the bare infinitive.